# Power Pivot Standard Deviation DAX measures

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot

I am trying to setup KPIs on a power pivot table that are based on a measure equation "Time per unit" and eventually another measure based on the deviation from the mean. The Standard Deviation equation I am currently using is looking at all the data table rows to calculate. I want it to reference the pivot table summary values, I have a feeling it is related to the "Allselected" but "filter","filters","keepselected", etc. have not worked. Formulas below, thank you for any help.

**Time per unit** = DIVIDE(SUM([Earntime]),SUM([Units]),BLANK())

**Standard Dev** = CALCULATE(STDEVX.P(Table1,[time per unit]),ALLSELECTED(Table1))

**Current Example of Pivot Table**
| Date | Sub Category Time per unit | StndDev.|
|:---- |:------:| -----:|
| 1/1/21  | 63.61   | 19.6 (Std Dev of data table)|
| 1/2/21  | 62.93   | 19.6 |
| 1/3/21  | 62.16   | 19.6 |
| 1/4/21  | 64.22   | 19.6 |

**Goal Example of Pivot Table**
| Date | Sub Category Time per unit | StndDev.|
|:---- |:------:| -----:|
| 1/1/21  | 63.61   | .76 (Std Dev of piv. summary values)|
| 1/2/21  | 62.93   | .76 |
| 1/3/21  | 62.16   | .76|
| 1/4/21  | 64.22   | .76 |

Comment: Are [Earntime] and [Units] column references or measures? I also see a column referring to subcategory so I assume that your data model contains at least 3 tables: Dates, Earntimes and Subcategories. Additionally I am going to assume that you have a slicer using a column from the subcategories table: Subcategories [SubcategoryName]. And finally I'm going to assume that you have dates (from the Dates table) in the rows and you want to compare the standard deviation for each date and for the selected subcategory with the standard deviation for each date but with respect to all subcategories.

Comment: If so, this would work: TpU_SD_ALLSubCat: = CALCULATE(STDEVX.P(EarnTimes,[TimePerUnit]),ALL(Subcategories)) where EarnTimes and Subcategories are two related tables. The first contains the column EarnTimes [EarnTime] used to calculate TimePerUnit and the second contains the column Subcategories [SubcategorieName] used in the filter